# MVVM setting default values

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm sure this is a pretty common scenario, and I would like to know how MVVM developers tackle this.

I have a ViewModel that is instantiated on demand, and persists until it is explicitly removed by the user. It's corresponding View is loaded onto the UI on demand. The View is able to unload and it's ViewModel may still exists in the application.

In my scenario, I have a ListBox of preset colors in the View(by setting it's ItemsSource to a Xaml-defined ObservableCollection of SolidColorBrush).

I bound the ListBox's SelectedItem property to a property in the ViewModel so that when the View is to be loaded again, the SelectedItem correctly shows the last selected item in the ListBox and also when the user selects a different color, the VM will handle the change.

My question is, how would u set the default value, say the third item in the ObservableCollection of SolidColorBrush to the ViewModel when the View is first loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Usually I set the defaults in the Constructor, unless the defaults may take some time to load, in which case I'll set call a method to set it in the getter for the bound property.

The reason for this is to simplify maintenance. If I am looking for where I set the default value so I can view or change it, the first place I check is the constructor. It's easier to find than scrolling through the properties, and is known to contain initialization logic.

```
MyViewModel()
{
    // Set defaults 
    SelectedColor = Brushes.Red;
}
```

For properties that may take longer to load, I use a method that is called in the getter for the same reason. Typically all my properties and their getters/setters are hidden in a region, and I find it much easier to find a method called `LoadColors()` in my class than finding the `Colors` properties in the huge list of properties I have. Also, it's reusable, so if I need to do something like reset the value, its easy to do so without repeating my code.

```
ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> Colors
{
    get
    {
        if (_colors == null)
            LoadColors();

        return _colors;
    }
    set { ... }
}

void LoadColors()
{
    // Initialization logic here
}
```

You can also set the default in your XAML by using the [FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) of the binding, however this usually only makes sense when there is a possibility of the binding's `DataContext` not existing when the binding is evaluated.

```
<!-- You may have to look up the exact syntax for Brushes.Red -->
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor, FallbackValue=Red}" />
```

And last but not least, you can always resort to code-behind the view to execute view-specific logic like your example. For example,

```
void ComboBox_Loaded(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: +1 for FallbackValue and advice me that it not only work's if the Binding is broken

Answer (score 1):

I believe you error is in your implementation. The reason to have MVVM is to have a "separation of concerns". That makes your view just an implementation, that can get switched or updated out if/when the need arises. Once you start putting stuff in your view that is part of the application logic, you are traveling down a path of a maintenance headache, and then spaghetti code can quickly ensue.

Some people say, "Don't put any code in your view", I agree 99% of the time. I say "Don't put any domain/application/business logic in your view."

Whenever you're trying to put some code into your view ask yourself "If I switched from WPF to another framework would my app still work?" If the answer is no, then modify your ViewModel to incorporate what you were trying to put in your view.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your POV. I have no intention of putting business logic in my View. I'm not sure where did you read on my comments that I'm putting code in my View... hmm? I also strongly believe the "separation of concerns" policy... in my implementation of MVVM, my ViewModel searches for it's corresponding View, my View has no command on it's creation of it's ViewModel. That is why i mentioned that my View may be destroyed but it's ViewModel still remains in memory. And when the user requests for it's View again, the View populates the last set properties on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

First read [Jose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396395/1993545) Answer if **your** answer to his question will be "**yes**" try this

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="icube.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="myLB" Margin="0,0,445,291"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding mySelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding mySelectedIndex,Mode=OneTime}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- or what ever yourTemplate will be-->
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SolidColorBrush}">
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>          
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Code-behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace icube
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var obcoll = new ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>();

            obcoll.Add(Brushes.Red);
            obcoll.Add(Brushes.Green);
            obcoll.Add(Brushes.Yellow);
            obcoll.Add(Brushes.Blue);
            obcoll.Add(Brushes.Orange);

            myLB.ItemsSource = obcoll;

            DataContext = new myClass();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //importent if you want to see your selected Element
            myLB.ScrollIntoView(myLB.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

### myClass

```
public class myClass
{
    private SolidColorBrush _mySelectedItem = new SolidColorBrush();
    public SolidColorBrush mySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set { _mySelectedItem = value; }
    }

    public int mySelectedIndex
    {
        get { return 4; }
    }
}
```

### summary

like you can see the default `SelectedItem` get setted by the `SelectedIndex` which is bounded per `OneTime` Mode to `mySelectedIndex`. I also show here how you could get it IntoView
i how this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

typically In MVVM your ObservableCollection of SolidBrushColor should be defined as a property in ViewModal. and this property should be bound to your ListBox. Now, to set default value you can have it in your ViewModal's constructor

Comment: as i've explained in my reply with akapoor, my ObservableCollection is defined at the View Level, not ViewModel level, that is why i would like to know how you guys would tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

If the property bound to SelectedItem is declared as dependency property then you can set the default value of the dependency propery to whatever you want.

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty
   = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(SolidBrushColor ), 
                                                typeof(<yourviewmodel>),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(GetDefaultColor()));

  Where GetDefaultColor() is a static method in your ViewModel, 
  which will return the required color from your ObservableCollection .
```

Comment: i'm using MVVM-light actually, therefore i'm not using DependencyProperty but using the INotifyPropertyChange interface. But that said, I get what you meant but the scenario here is my ObservableCollection is defined in the View level not in the ViewModel as this is a Color collection, the Designer is able to modify the Preset Colors on his side, and also able to set the Default Color on his side.

Comment: In that case either of following can be useful 
1. Pass the default value as parameter to your view model constructor 
2. Use Converter and ConverterParameter in xaml where you are binding ListBox SelectedItem to ViewModel Property.